# Error saving incorrect version of SSIS package in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to save a SSIS package for an export of a query to a `.csv` file. The problem is that the PackageFormatVersion of said SSIS package is 8 (for SQL Server 2016 onwards) but the instance I'm using is SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have uninstalled the newer instance that I had previously and 2008 is the only one I currently have but it still saves the SSIS package for the newer version, when it should be PackageFormatVersion = "3". Plus, the only way I have of saving the SSIS package is to the file system. If I try to save it to SQL Server it gives me an error saying that the SSIS runtime and the target database should be the same version.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: If you are *still* using SQL Server 2008 (R2) you'll need to find a copy of Visual Studio 2008 and BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Services..? I honestly can't remember what the acronym stood for). The *real* solution is get updated; 2008 (R2) ran *completely* out of support over 4 years ago.

Comment: @ThomA thanks, unfortunately I'm working for a company that still uses SQL 2008 suppousedly due to a licencing problem, so I have to figure things like these. I'll try to fix that and comment again if it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @AleYanczuk there's no licensing problem. They simply didn't want to pay to upgrade 9 years ago when this was cheap, and now they don't want to pay for a completely new server and a complex migration across 4 major versions. You can't use later SSIS package versions in older SQL Server versions, especially not when there's such a huge gap. An SSIS package is an XML file referencing the .NET components used by SSIS. A newer SSIS package is looking for newer versions of not only the components but the .NET too. Native components in 2010 became .NET components in 2014 and later

Comment: Uninstalling SSIS won't change the contents of the package. BIDS referred to the customized VS version used to edit SSIS packages. In VS 2019, that's available as a Visual Studio Extension. The *SSIS project format* itself changed in 2014 (if not earlier) though, and I'm not sure VS 2019 can save in the old format. Visual Studio doesn't have to support completely unsupported project versions

Comment: Not even Visual Studio 2010 with SSDT (which included SSIS back then) supported SSIS 2008 packages, @PanagiotisKanavos. I *think* the project format changed with 2012 too, as SSIS in VS 2019 supports 2012-2022, and I'm still using the same project I initially created back in 2013 at work. VS2022, however, only supports 2014 onwards iirc (it might be 2016 onwards).

Comment: @ThomA I've tried installing those but SSMS still exports the SSIS package for newer versions. I now know there is no licensing problem but I have to stick with 2008 for the time being. I'll try to install an older version of SSMS too but I'll see if it works. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: What do you mean by it exports it as a newer version? The only deployment methods for SSSIS in 2008 were file system, which would mean you don't export the package as you just grab it from the file system, and made (which requires you connect the the SSIS service and that "had* to be SSMS 2008 back then, SSMS 2012 wouldn't work). SSISDB didn't exist in 2008.